# 404 servlet not found error in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I'm working on a dynamic web project on eclipse IDE. My web.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>TestTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>NewServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is my javascript code..
    **Example.js:**

```
$.ajax('/NewServlet',params,function(result) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(result);
                    alert(json.data);
                });
```

When I created the NewServlet.java, it didn't get automatically mapped in web.xml. I just manually entered it. Still I'm getting this error ***404 not found***

NewServlet.java file path is Java Resources->src->(DefaultPackage)->NewServlet.java

Example.js file path WebContent->Js->Example.js

Comment: Are you sure **your** server is running on port 80? Check the log. The server will usually tell you on which port it's listening when it is starting

Comment: Yes .. It's correct. But I'm running on localhost. When I load my index.jsp file, the URL seems to be http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.jsp and when the servlet has to be loaded, the URL changes to http://localhost:8080/NewServlet ... It should be http://localhost:8080/MyApp/NewServlet ... ???? @litelite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in AJAX call.
It should be something like this :
 `$.ajax('NewServlet',params,function(result) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(result);
                    alert(json.data);
                });`

Without "/" check out [here](http://www.journaldev.com/4742/jquery-ajax-jsp-servlet-java-example) for example of AJAX call to Servlet.

Hope this helps.